# Rounded Boxes using x11names package

Tags: color, boxes

I was wondering if I could make an empty rounded box with x11names package with math environment. Thank you!

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please provide a [full minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) which reproduces the issue, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, `x11names` is not a package but just a collection of color names. You can use them e.g. in `tcolorbox` to produce a colored frame in math environments. Of course, a box can be empty, or contain a `\phantom`, say.